# Best solution of using magento API

Tags: api, rest, magento, soap, mobile-application

I need to create a native android and ios app. I've done some tests on SOAP API but that was very slow (I don't know why!) I've tried REST API as well but the methods are very limited and I don't know how should I handle "add to basket" and "checkout" parts.
Is it sensible to create the app based on REST API and use SOAP just for "add to basket" and "checkout" parts?

Answer (score 0):

Sincerely SOAP API when cached is not much slower than REST, thought from the programming experience REST is much much nicer than SOAP, I am developing an api in SOAP at the moment I find him extremely restrictive, and annoying for the mobile developers json responses for them will be easier to use.

The ideea of using SOAP for some methods is not that good, cause implementing the SOAP handlers for mobile is a drag. So you should orient into REST.

A `pro` to use SOAP in magento, is that it's grown to maturity little bugs, and has a nice security implimentation.